# The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run

Tags: system-installation

I'm getting the above message (please note it is important to the narrative) on booting from USB.  I never got it before.  But I am running Windows, so maybe some Windows updates have caused havoc.

Previously I got the options of 'try' or 'install'.

I would now like to install Ubuntu (and have shrunk a partition to allow this).  But it seems I cannot.  After opening the deskop session, everything seems to work fine, apart from the 'Install Ubuntu 20.4' link which does nothing.

How the heck can I diagnose what the problem is?  Where do I find the diagnostic information regarding the above error message?

Comment: I am tempted to send this laptop to landfill and just get another.  There might be something wrong with it.  Or it might be that Windows with latest updates no longer works with only 4Gb RAM.  But, unlike most people and their pushers, I don't like chucking out electronic goods after just 2-3 years of service.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO prior to writing to your install media? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  If I have issues (with *live* installation media); the first I do is switch to a text terminal & look for clues as to issues, esp. whether or not the self-validation completed (`journalctl` for example) successfully (if it didn't - I don't waste any more time & correct the write to install media)...

Comment: @guiverc The ISO / USB flash is fine.  I have used it on several occasions.  As pointed out, it will run Ubuntu desktop.  Just the install options are malfunctioning (probably due to some hardware issue which is also causing problems for Windows, but I'd like to know what).

Comment: I've re-flashed the USB drive.  Now I am not getting the original error, but wi-fi is completely missing.  It's not there at all in the top-right of the desktop.  This shouldn't be such a PITA.

Comment: Managed to get it installed.  It seems if you click 'install' instead of 'try' on start-up wi-fi is permanantly disabled.  My question is not answered, and the installtion process remains a shambles.  Diagnostic information should be made available.  I thought Windows was pretty terrible, but my experience so far with Ubuntu has not been good.  I am not too stupid to understand more informative error messages than the absolutely ridiculous "sorry, something went wrong".